# ANN model.predict fails when expanding dimension using array notation and succeeds with np.expand_dim

Tags: python, neural-network

Given the following testing dataset `tst_images`

```
print(tst_images.shape)
print(np.shape([tst_images[0]]))
print(np.shape(np.expand_dims(tst_images[i], axis=0)))
```

and the shapes before and after expanding dimension in 2 ways

```
(750, 45, 45)
(1, 45, 45)
(1, 45, 45)
```

given a NN model

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[45,45]),
                                        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
```

trying a prediction, succeeds for 1 expansion and fails for the other

```
prediction = model.predict([tst_images[i]]) #fails
prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(tst_images[i], axis=0)) #succeeds
```

Error on fail

```
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_28" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2025, but received input with shape (None, 45)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_14' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 45), dtype=float32)',)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

why the difference?